# FTP - Connection refused - Ubuntu ::: Get message Connection refused when trying to connect to other computer in network

Tags: linux, networking, shell, ftp, ip-address

I Get message Connection refused when trying to connect to other computer in network.

My System Ubuntu:

computer1 ip: 10.0.0.1

computer2 ip: 10.0.0.2

computer1 shell:

```
$ ftp
ftp> open 10.0.0.2
ftp: connect: Connection refused
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: please show us the iptables rules of the pcs and the output of netstat -lnt on the ftp serving pc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a number of things.

- Your router could be configured to not allow cross network connections.

  - Check your router settings.
- Your receiving computer could have a firewall that is blocking this request.

  - Check in the /var/logs/ directory for  security iptables or ufw logs.
- Your sending computer could have a firewall blocking the request out.
- Your ftpd could be configured on a different port?

Comment: Thanks,which commands should i do inj shell to check options that you write?